# How to build those rectangular with picture and text css bootsrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to add a section like those 3 side to side on the airbnb website "https://www.airbnb.com/" Montreal, Toronto, Quebec. And in uber webpage those six boxes, one tap to ride, reliable pick up, .....Split your fare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) might do the job for you. 
Or you can simply use [Bootstrap grids](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).